# Matlab : Get list of all the text files in the directory folder

Tags: matlab

I want to get the list of text files in the current folder using Matlab code. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic syntax to look for a directory is the following:

```
SomeVariableName = dir('*.txt');
```

which will output a structure containing the following fields:

```
    name
    date
    bytes
    isdir
    datenum
```

So if your interested in the names of the files you can access them like this:

```
Name(Index) = SomeVariableName(Index).name
```

and so on for the other fields. What do you want to do with those files?